# c3 js bar chart - setting a minimum bar height

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I've got a chart with a wide variance in Y values (2 - 10000).  Unfortunately, this causes the bars at the lower end of the scale to be only a few pixels tall, and thus invisible/non-interactable.  Is there any way I can set a minimum height for the bars? I know in pure d3 you can fudge the domain a little if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Logarithm is a nonlinear transformation, helps in keeping small values little small and very large values to relatively very small.

Hence you should be able to see both 3 and 30000 in the c3 charts if logarithmic scale is somehow applied.

But make sure to inform user that logarithmic scale is used and, visually 500 might look 2 times of height of 5 (if plotted in a chart).

c3.js doesn't support logarithmic scales via configuration, hence you need to yourself convert the data to be in log scale(prepprocess) and feed this to linear scale c3.js charts (default scale in c3).

There are already few users asking c3 developers to provide way to plug-in d3 log,power and other scales to c3 charts.

https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/252

But you can try above method(preprocess data to log scale) for now.

**Example:-**

ln(5000) = 8.517

ln(500) = 6.214

ln(50) = 3.912

ln(5) = 1.609

As you can see from the above example that both 5000 and 5 can be seen in the same chart if log scale is used in y axis.

Comment: While this shows the bar as requested, it converts the underlying data, which makes the chart less useful. Is there a way to preserve the actual value of the data (at least for labeling purposes), and also change the scale somehow?